# How do I stay DRY?

Tags: python, django, django-models, dry

I'm writing some string representations for the data in a django model and my code gets quite repetitive. What would be the best way to stay out of the rain?

Here is two of the methods:

```
def get_known_citys_string(user):
    entrys = HTTPRequestData.objects.filter(user=user)
    counter = Counter()

    for entry in entrys:
        counter[entry.city] += 1

    return counter_to_string(counter)

def get_known_devices_string(user):
    entrys = HTTPRequestData.objects.filter(user=user)
    counter = Counter()

    for entry in entrys:
        counter[entry.device] += 1

    return counter_to_string(counter)
```

Comment: Your aware of your code repetition, try to refractor them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this.  Here's one:

```
def get_known_fields_string(user, fieldSelector):
    entrys = HTTPRequestData.objects.filter(user=user)
    counter = Counter()

    for entry in entrys:
        counter[fieldSelector(entry)] += 1

    return counter_to_string(counter)

def get_known_citys_string(user):
    return get_known_fields_string(user, lambda entry: entry.city)

def get_known_devices_string(user):
    return get_known_fields_string(user, lambda entry: entry.device)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's why functions were invented...

```
def common(user, field):
    entrys = HTTPRequestData.objects.filter(user=user)
    counter = Counter()

    for entry in entrys:
        counter[getattr(entry, field)] += 1

    return counter_to_string(counter)

def get_known_citys_string(user):
    return common(user, "city")

def get_known_devices_string(user):
    return common(user, "device")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html), for that succinct functional flavour:

```
from functools import partial


def getter(attrname, user):
    entrys = HTTPRequestData.objects.filter(user=user)
    counter = Counter()

    for entry in entrys:
        counter[getattr(entry, attrname)] += 1

    return counter_to_string(counter)


# Define functions as variations on getter
get_known_citys_string = partial(getter, 'city')
get_known_devices_string = partial(getter, 'device')
```